# Difficulty to list taxonomy terms in a block for specific content type (d7)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks, views, i18n-l10n

I have made a page using views to list a specific content type.
Then I wanted to make a block to list a taxonomy vocabulary in a sidebar in order to sort the posts according to terms.

The problems I am facing are:

1. If I select the block to appear for specific content types, the block doesn't show
2. I am having a multilingual website and the block shows terms in both languages, how do I choose to show the terms in the current users language?
3. I have also tried the module taxonomy menu but it also lists terms in both languages and doesn't show for specific content types

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I remember, views already has a filter, current language. Did you apply that filter?

Answer (score 0):

To get the block to appear on certain content types you will need to get the common URL for the content types you are looking to put it on.  You may have to use a module like [pathauto](http://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) to set better URLs for your content.  For example if you are on an article content and the URL is www.example.com/article/3 you would go to the block configuration and at the bottom choose to show blocks only on certain pages.  Then in the text box type the urls of the content types you want them to show on.  Again as Article content type as an example you would enter: article/* or just simply article* like so:
[image: block configuration page]